# How to decide which "outliers" to get rid of?

Tags: econometrics, outliers, finance

I have thinking about this problem for a while but couldn't quite formulate a proper solution myself. I am also not even sure if it is appropriate to speak of "outliers" or if the term "unsuitable values" would be more suitable.

Summarizing my problem in a few bullet points:

- my (panel)dataset contains bank balance sheet and income statement values from 2010-2017
- I am trying to implement a DiD regression with net interest margins
- net interest margins I've calculated myself by dividing "Net Income" through "Total Gross Loans"

Unsurprisingly I get a lot of Inf & -Inf values when doing this since some banks in the dataset have gross loans of 0 (which does not make economic sense).

After removing these observations I still have a lot of observations in the dataset in which the net interest margin has unreasonable values such as >1000%, which also is due the fact that some figures of those banks reported just don't add up (e.g. bank reports net interest income without having a lot of loans on the balance sheet).

My question now is what strategy you would take on such a dataset to get rid of these values?
I already thought about using "technical" / econometric strategies such as using IQR ranges and then define cutoff values. However, this would be a technique to deal with actual outliers. I wouldn't say that my values are outliers though, rather just implausible values.

Can I just define certain cutoff levels myself?
Or would it make sense ex ante, before the calculation, already throw out all the banks with little loans on their balance sheet?

Thank you

Comment: An outlier is by definition an implausible value, i.e. one that's so extreme you think it's not real. Techniques meant to deal with outliers are supposed to be "Mostly accurate" even if your data is contaminated by incorrect measurements.

Comment: To be clear, your problem is that you think a lot of the results in your data is *incorrect*, i.e. the values have been entered or measured incorrectly, right? As in, 1000% returns mean that the numbers in your dataset are just wrong. As an example of your data being "Not wrong" -- maybe these weird-looking banks make most of their profits off charging transaction fees, rather than loan interest. Then the values might need to be modeled differently.

Comment: First step would be to plot a histogram of the values for the entire dataset. It is possible that reasonable bounds for defining 'plausible' values will show up naturally. Quite likely there need not be a more formal specification of 'outlier' for your purposes.